# After cropping and writing in png file the size of some images has changed,why?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, medical

My images are in mat file after I cropped them with a particular size 256x256, the size was correct before  writing in png file. I saved them in png format. Now, I wanted to process them and realized that the sizes are not same, what is the reason? And how can I solve it? Thanks

This the code:

```
[m1,m2] = size(II);


i1_start = floor((m1)/2)-floor(n/2); % or round instead of floor; using neither gives warning
i1_stop = i1_start + n;

i2_start = floor((m2)/2)-floor(n/2);
i2_stop = i2_start + n;

B = II(i1_start+1:i1_stop, i2_start+1:i2_stop);

figure ,imshow(B,[]);
```

and this is the code for png conversion:

```
 outfile = sprintf(png_filename) 
data=uint8(data);
imwrite(data,outfile,'png','BitDepth' ,8);
```

Comment: How did you crop the images and save them to pngs? please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Use imwrite function

```
A = rand(50);
imwrite(A,'myGray.png')
```